# APIs to extract numbers from images?

Tags: python, api, ocr

I'm working on an app, and I need a way to extract numbers from images similar to how banking apps extract your credit card number from a picture. I don't have any preference on language but probably Python would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the LEADTOOLS SDK to perform OCR, on images for text and numbers. Here is a small code snippet in C API which you could probably connect to a python application in some way. As a disclaimer, this is a paid for SDK and I work for the vendor.

https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/ocr/api/l-ocrpage-gettext.html

```
   BITMAPHANDLE bitmap = { 0 }; 
   L_OcrEngine ocrEngine = NULL; 
   L_OcrPage ocrPage = NULL; 
 
   // Create an instance of the engine 
   std::wcout << L"Creating OCR engine instance...\n"; 
   L_INT retCode = L_OcrEngineManager_CreateEngine(L_OcrEngineType_Advantage, &ocrEngine); 
   if(retCode != SUCCESS) 
      return retCode; 
 
   // Start the engine using default parameters 
   std::wcout << L"Starting up OCR engine...\n"; 
   L_OcrEngine_Startup(ocrEngine, NULL, OCR_ADVANTAGE_RUNTIME_DIR); 
 
   // Load an image to process 
   std::wcout << L"Loading page to process...\n"; 
   L_LoadBitmap(MAKE_IMAGE_PATH(L_TEXT("Ocr1.tif")), &bitmap, sizeof(BITMAPHANDLE), 0, ORDER_RGB, NULL, NULL); 
 
   // Create an OCR page to handle processing 
   L_OcrPage_FromBitmap(ocrEngine, &ocrPage, &bitmap, L_OcrBitmapSharingMode_AutoFree, NULL, NULL); 
 
   // Transfer ownership 
   bitmap.Flags.Allocated = 0; 
 
   // Find text in the image 
   std::wcout << L"Finding text within page...\n"; 
   L_OcrPage_AutoZone(ocrPage, NULL, NULL); 
 
   // Recognize the text 
   std::wcout << L"Recognizing the text...\n"; 
   L_OcrPage_Recognize(ocrPage, NULL, NULL); 
 
   // Loop through zones and output the text 
   L_UINT zoneCount = 0; 
   L_OcrPage_GetZoneCount(ocrPage, &zoneCount); 
 
   std::wcout << L"Zone count: " << zoneCount << std::endl; 
   std::wcout << L"Show recognized text:\n"  
      << L"**********************************************\n"; 
   for(L_UINT zoneIndex = 0; zoneIndex < zoneCount; zoneIndex++) 
   { 
      L_WCHAR* text = NULL; 
      L_UINT textLength = 0; 
      L_OcrPage_GetText(ocrPage, zoneIndex, &text, &textLength); 
 
      std::wcout << text << std::endl; 
 
      L_OcrMemory_Free(text); 
   } 
 
   std::wcout << L"**********************************************\n"; 
 
   //CLEANUP 
   std::wcout << L"Disposing of resources used..."; 
   L_OcrPage_Destroy(ocrPage); 
   L_OcrEngine_Destroy(ocrEngine);
```